# Devise new sessions issue with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have recently implemented carrier wave with my application so posts can have a picture, but I am running into errors when I try to log into my application. Here is the result when running `heroku logs`:

```
    2017-10-16T20:14:41.944943+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:2149:in `do_delivery'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944943+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `block in deliver'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944944+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:558:in `block in deliver_mail'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944944+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944945+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944945+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944945+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:556:in `deliver_mail'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944946+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `deliver'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944946+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:96:in `block in deliver_now'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944947+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:15:in `handle_exceptions'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944947+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:95:in `deliver_now'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944948+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:191:in `send_devise_notification'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944948+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:119:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944948+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:126:in `send_reconfirmation_instructions'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944949+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944949+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260:in `block in conditional'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944950+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944950+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944951+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944950+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944966+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944967+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:343:in `committed!'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944968+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:86:in `commit_records'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944969+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `block in commit_transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944970+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:168:in `commit_transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944969+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944970+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `block in within_new_transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944971+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944972+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944972+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944973+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944974+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944973+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944975+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944975+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944976+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944977+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:92:in `set_reset_password_token'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944977+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:49:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944980+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944978+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:134:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944980+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944979+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2017-10-16T20:14:41.944978+00:00 app[web.1]: [4e6c03b3-5414-44a7-883b-b0ba34b62b6a] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

---

I was wondering what my error is here or if anybody has direction as to what I should be looking to fix? I don't know how to fix this problem. Have spent a few hours googling, but haven't found anything that resembles this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just resetting this whole database to fix it (I am still working in development, so this was not a big deal). If you are having trouble with this in production, I would recommend using `rails console` to manually reset your user's password. This should help fix the problem. I was also having issues with connecting to Heroku as a result of my ISP blocking the 5000 port to be able to run `heroku run rails console`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is a password was changed and Devise is wanted to send out an email and there is a problem with the mailer

Sign-up for a free heroku mail addon, set it up, configure devise to send emails, and restart your dyno

*Mail Issue*

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:2149:in `do_delivery'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `block in deliver'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:558:in `block in deliver_mail'
```

*Devise Trigger*

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:134:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Comment: I've already added the following code to my project and have had Sendgrid working for a while: `Rails.application.initialize!
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}`

Comment: Try removing `:recoverable` and `:confirmable` from your devise setup on your model